# How to make all key combinations insert themselves into vterm?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, insert, prefix-keys, self-insert-command

I'd like to create a keymap `vterm-insert-map` for `vterm` that self-inserts all or at least all currently bound key combinations, except for one, which acts as an escape key. I can use `set-transient-map` to overlay that keymap over all active ones and I can use `(make-composed-keymap (current-active-maps t))` to put all bound key combinations into one. I thought about using `mapcar` to simply replace the second part of each key-value pair with `vterm--self-insert` but the trouble is that `vterm` uses `vterm--self-insert-meta` to apply the meta-modifier, so I need to bind keys with a meta-prefix to `vterm--self-insert-meta` and I'm assuming similar for super-prefixes. But `(make-composed-keymap (current-active-maps t))` returns the key combinations as numbers. How do I from that find out from those whether the combination uses meta or not? Or does someone have another idea for how to make such a map?

Comment: Do the variable `vterm-keymap-exceptions` (read its doc string) and the function [`vterm--exclude-keys`](https://github.com/akermu/emacs-libvterm/blob/master/vterm.el#L615) help? For example, `(setopt vterm-keymap-exceptions '("C-c"))`, makes vterm pass all keys except `C-c` to the terminal. They aren't inserted literally (that requires prefixing them with `C-q`, just like in other terminals) but they aren't hijacked by Emacs either. I don't know how to wrap that up in a keymap but I hope it helps you find a way.

Comment: @ArchStanton That helps, but even if I remove all keys from that it doesn't send through all key combinations because a lot of them just aren't in the vterm-mode-map.

Comment: Compare with `M-x term`.  If `term` handles the keys (in its char mode), and `vterm` does not, then you can compare how the keymaps are set up, and raise a vterm issue for the differences.  (If it happens that `term` also doesn't handle these keys, then maybe vterm already used the term.el keymaps as a basis.)

Comment: Moreover, if it's your understanding that terminals should handle the keys in question, and they don't, it would be appropriate to raise upstream bug reports.